# confusion about conditional type parameters; why won't this compile?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why doesn't g compile? The error message is `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T extends string ? boolean : Number'.` which seems kind of weird since T does extend string, so a boolean should be accepted.

```
const f = <T>(x: T, y: T extends string ? boolean : Number) => y;
const g = <T extends string>(x: T) => f(x, true); // won't compile
```

> edited on 10/16 to simplify my code example. oops, by editing it the comment/answer below may not make sense anymore. sorry!

Comment: Unrelated tip: Use `%o` in `console.log` instead of abusing interpolated strings, e.g.  `console.log( "value: %o", y );`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `f2` allows any subtype of `string`. `T extends string` does not mean at all that `T` is a string in a way you expect.

Consider this example:

```js
declare var char: 'a' & { toString: (a: number) => [1, 2, 3] };

const expectString = <T extends string>(str: T) => str

const result = expectString(char).toString(42) // [1, 2, 3]
result.concat() // BOOM, runtime error
```

You can find similar example in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints).

These function works:

```js
f("abc", true);
```

because TS is 100% sure that `abc` is a string without any surpsises.

**UPDATE**

```js
const f = <T,>(x: T, y: T extends string ? boolean : Number) => y;
const g = <T extends string>(x: T) => f(x, true); // won't compile
```

function `g` failed, because `x` has type `T`. It is black boxed generic. All that we know about it is that `T` extends `string`. This generic is not `unwrapped/evaluated` yet.
It means , that `f` expect second argument to have a type `T extends string ? boolean : Number` and not just `boolean`.

Now, when you know that `T` might be any subtype of a `string`, it is unsafe for TS to assume that `T` is just a string. That's why this conditional statement `T extends string ? boolean : Number` is not evaluated.

IF you want to make it work you can `assert` it :

```js
const g = <T extends string>(x: T) => f(x, true as T extends string ? boolean : Number);
```

This is wrong anf ugly way to meka thing work in typescript. But it shows you that second argument expects a conditional statement because `T` is not infered.

Comment: Trying to get my head around this. I think you're saying "extends string" means it is a string plus a bunch of other unpredictable stuff. with branding you could add stuff. you could add a toString method that replaces the original version and throws an exception. so i can see how you'd end up with runtime errors where a normal string is expected. but i still don't understand why you'd get compile errors - see my vastly simplified example. i'll read your article; maybe it will help me understand.

Comment: @JustinM I made an update

Comment: You can pass a `string & [1, 2, 3] & { happy: () => Number }` to function f and Typescript doesn't complain; don't think Typescript is worried about safety or expecting anything to exactly equal a string. I think you're saying that f always expects the second argument to have a complex conditional type - two paths - and there is no way to force it to go down just one of those paths. Practically I've got a conditional function like f and want to generate 2 separate wrapper functions for it - but it doesn't seem possible.